# array merge php with same index

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework

I have this situation:

```
$qty = array(1) {[0]=> array(1) { ["qty"]=> string(5) "35254" }
$price = array(1) {[0]=> array(1) { ["price"]=> string(5) "1000" }
```

How can I get this?

```
$res = array(1) {[0]=> array(1) { ["qty"]=> string(5) "35254" ["price"]=> string(5) "1000"}
```

Thanks for the answers

Comment: what is the purpose of having multidimensional arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be it's that you want:

```
$res = array();
foreach($qty as $k => $v){
    $res[$k] = array_merge($qty[$k],$price[$k]);
}
```

The result :

```
array(1) {[0] => array(2) { 'qty' => string(5) "35254" 'price' => string(4) "1000" } }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$qty = array("qty"=>"35254" );
$price = array ( "price"=> "1000" );

$combine = array_merge($qty,$price);
var_dump($combine);
```

Comment: This is not the sample input.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$res = array_merge_recursive($qty, $price);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: You could also use $res = array_merge($qty[0], $price[0]); Depends on your use-case

Comment: This answer does not work with the asker's sample data. https://3v4l.org/2lOFI

Answer (score 0):

Not as pretty but with the same result.

```
$result = array_map(function ($e1,$e2) {
    return array_merge_recursive($e1, $e2);
}, $qty,$price);

$result =
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["qty"]=>
        string(5) "35254"
        ["price"]=>
        string(4) "1000"
      }
    }
```

and for indexed arrays

```
$a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$n = [1, 2, 3];

$result = array_map(function ($e1,$e2) {
    return [$e1, $e2];
}, $a,$n);

$result = [
 0 => ['a', 1],
 1 => ['b', 2],
 2 => ['c', 3]
];
```

Comment: This question is not asking for the transposition of two indexed arrays.  If it was, it would be written as `array_map(null, $a, $n);`.

Comment: It would "prettier" to call `array_merge_recursive()` by its string name, but I still wouldn't. https://3v4l.org/iKuNb