# PHP - How to properly merge 2 arrays multi level in this example?

Tags: php, arrays, merge, array-merge

I have the follow array:

```
$arrIni["ENV"]="US";   
$arrIni["sap_db_server"] = "192.xxx.x.xx";

$arrIni["local_db_server"] = "localhost";
$arrIni["local_db_username"] = "root";

//Default settings
$arrIni["arrEnvSettings"]["UserTypeID"]=4;       
$arrIni["arrEnvSettings"]["LocalizationID"]=1;
$arrIni["arrEnvSettings"]["LangLabels"] = array();
$arrIni["arrEnvSettings"]["pages"]["st1"]="st1.php";
$arrIni["arrEnvSettings"]["pages"]["st2"]="st2.php";
$arrIni["arrEnvSettings"]["pages"]["st3"]="st3.php";
```

And I want to merge with this one:

```
$setParam["arrEnvSettings"]["pages"]["st3"]="st3_V2.php";
```

This is what I am doing:

```
echo "<pre>";
    print_r(array_merge($arrIni,$setParam));
echo "</pre>";
```

And this is what I am getting:

```
Array
(
    [ENV] => US
    [sap_db_server] => 192.xxx.x.xx
    [local_db_server] => localhost
    [local_db_username] => root
    [arrEnvSettings] => Array
        (
            [pages] => Array
                (
                    [st3] => st3_V2.php
                )

        )

)
```

In the [php doc about merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), this is the comment `" ...If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. ..."`

So in this way, I suppose to get this output instead of the last one:

```
Array
(
    [ENV] => US
    [sap_db_server] => 192.xxx.x.xx
    [local_db_server] => localhost
    [local_db_username] => root
    [arrEnvSettings] => Array
        (
            [UserTypeID] => 4
            [LocalizationID] => 1
            [LangLabels] => Array
                (
                )

            [pages] => Array
                (
                    [st1] => st1.php
                    [st2] => st2.php
                    [st3] => st3_V2.php
                )

        )

)
```

I do not understand why `$setParam["arrEnvSettings"]["pages"]["st3"]` is overriding the entire `$arrIni["arrEnvSettings"]`.

Note:

If I use `array_merge_recursive($arrIni,$setParam))` I will have the follow result but it is not what I want.

```
Array
(
    [ENV] => US
    [sap_db_server] => 192.xxx.x.xx
    [local_db_server] => localhost
    [local_db_username] => root
    [arrEnvSettings] => Array
        (
            [UserTypeID] => 4
            [LocalizationID] => 1
            [LangLabels] => Array
                (
                )

            [pages] => Array
                (
                    [st1] => st1.php
                    [st2] => st2.php
                    [st3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => st3.php
                            [1] => st3_V2.php
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Is there a way to do this without [iterate over the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426025/array-merge-php-with-same-index)? Only using merging? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you getting the correct array before merging, however after merging you have the 3 values deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`array_replace_recursive($arrIni,$setParam);`

Comment: That function works good. Can we understand that `array_replace_recursive()` can fully replace  `array_merge_recursive()` and `array_merge()`?

Comment: I don't think so. That depends on what kind of problem you need to solve. In your case, array_replace_recursive is the way to go, but sometimes you need to overwrite keys, so you use array_merge.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to merge a given value, use this:

```
$arrIni["arrEnvSettings"]["pages"]["st3"] = $setParam["arrEnvSettings"]["pages"]["st3"];
```

But the way you're doing it is merging two arrays, not simply setting the value within an array. There's a gigantic difference between those two methods.

Otherwise, yes you will need to iteratively merge the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is array_replace_recursive

```
print_r(array_replace_recursive($arrIni,$setParam));
```

didnt see the submitted answer..Felippe Duarte has given it already.....