# Push elements from a flat array into an object array by related index

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have two arrays like below:

array 1:

```
array([0]=> 11, [1] => 2.5)
```

array  2:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [type] => 1 
        [creator_id] => 3 
        [creator_name] => E1 
        [per_tar] => 300 
        [pro_tar] => 200 
        [ac] => 300 
        [PA] => 17 
        [Q1] => 800 
    ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
        [type] => 1 
        [creator_id] => 4 
        [creator_name] => E2 
        [per_tar] => 100 
        [pro_tar] => 170 
        [ac] => 0 
        [PA] => 7 
        [Q1] => 270 
    ) 
)
```

I want is to merge the first array with the second array with the following logic:

Array 1 key [0] is merged inside array 2 key [0] object, and so on in the same fashion for all keys.

So my expected output is:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [type] => 1 
        [creator_id] => 3 
        [creator_name] => E1 
        [per_tar] => 300 
        [pro_tar] => 200 
        [ac] => 300 
        [PA] => 17 
        [Q1] => 800
        [new] => 11 
    ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( 
        [type] => 1 
        [creator_id] => 4 
        [creator_name] => E2 
        [per_tar] => 100 
        [pro_tar] => 170 
        [ac] => 0 
        [PA] => 7 
        [Q1] => 270
        [new] => 2.5 
    ) 
)
```

I am trying the `array_merge()` function, but it's incorrectly merging both arrays into a four-element array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array merge php with same index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26426025/array-merge-php-with-same-index)

Comment: i am getting this error array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

Comment: can you show any example

Comment: array-object has the method `toArray()`. If you have ArrayObjects nested inside the ArrayObject I am afraid this will not work, as `toArray()` does not recurse. You would need to solve this with a custom method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$res = [];
foreach($array1 as $key => $val){
    // before merging convert object to array
    $arr = is_object($array2[$key]) ? (array)$array2[$key] : $array2[$key];  
    $res[$key] = array_merge($array1[$key], $arr);
}

print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should iterate `$array1` items and insert value of every item into relevant index of `$array2`.

```
foreach ($array1 as $key=>$value){
    $array2[$key]->new = $value;
}
```

See result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/gsH6j)

Also if you want to remain `array2`, copy value of it in new variable like `$newArray`.

```
$newArray = $array2;
foreach ($array1 as $key=>$value){
    $newArray[$key]->new = $value;
}
```

Comment: i have an doubt. if my array 2 have 1 key  means  i am getting Creating default object from empty value  error how to solve this

Comment: @Nisanth You should check if target index exist in `$array2` then set new property in it. See https://3v4l.org/GPRPV

Answer (score -1):

Best bet would be to convert the stdClass object to an array then just use array_merge.

convert the stdClass object to an array like so:

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
```

Comment: What's wrong with
$array = (array) $object;